# .htaccess 301 redirect one subdomain to another, for multiple TLDs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to change a subdomain of my site and would like to make the RewriteRules I use to 301 users more simple, as currently I have to have multiple rules to cover various eventualities.

Is there a way that with one rule I can do the following:

```
subold.domain.com -> subnew.domain.com
subold.domain.co.uk -> subnew.domain.co.uk
subold.domain.local -> subnew.domain.local
subold-staging.domain.com -> subnew-staging.domain.com
subold-staging.domain.co.uk -> subnew-staging.domain.co.uk
subold-staging.domain.local -> subnew-staging.domain.local
```

So basically, I need to detect the presence of `subold` in the host, change this to `subnew` and redirect to this new subdomain, preserving whichever TLD the user tried to access.

At the minute, my rules are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold.domain.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subnew.domain.local/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold-staging.domain.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subnew-staging.domain.local/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subnew.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold-staging.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subnew-staging.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold.domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subnew.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold-staging.domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subnew-staging.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is just a difference of `subold vs subnew` in your real domain names.

You can have just one rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subold\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subnew.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```